# How to create Pivot Tables using Google Sheets API v4 for Java?

Tags: java, google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-api

Any pointers to examples/documentation for creating pivot tables for a spreadsheet created using Google Sheets API V4?

My workflow is as follows,

1. Pull data from required data source.
2. Create Spreadsheet, specify sheet properties.
3. Upload the data to the spreadsheet

Now, after this, I am trying to create a pivot table from the data uploaded to the spreadsheet.

The data fields that I have are, Date, UserId, Activity_Name, Activity_Timestamp.

The Pivot I am trying to populate is, the number of all activities of a user for a particular day.

The extremely rough and initial code that I could figure out from the API documentation is,

```
    PivotTable pivot = new PivotTable();
    GridRange pivotGridRange = new GridRange();
    pivotGridRange.setSheetId(createdSheet.getProperties().getSheetId());
    pivotGridRange.setStartColumnIndex(0);
    pivotGridRange.setEndColumnIndex(3);
    pivot.setSource(pivotGridRange);
```

How do I go ahead? 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: Herer is the answer to create a pivot table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879012/google-sheet-api-unable-to-load-file-when-clicked-in-pivot-table/54879482#54879482

Answer (score 1):

**The guide documentation**, including *sample code which works* (multiple languages), and links to github for that code, is here:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/pivot-tables

I don't know whether that page existed when the question was originally posted, but since searches still seem to be leading to this post, I figure the link should help.

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to create a Pivot Table via the v4 API, I suggest first creating one in the UI and doing a spreadsheets.get (https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to retrieve the pivot table.  Examine how it's constructed, and craft yours in a similar manner.

Pivot tables are one of the more complicated parts of the API and are difficult to explain well.

Comment: Using the Java API, the get method with setValueRenderOption = "FORMULA" returns nothing, and with setValueRenderOption = UNFORMATTED_VALUE or FORMATTED_VALUE just returns the data presented by the pivot table.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you try query. Assuming your data is Sheet1, on Sheet2 enter:

=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:C5,"SELECT A,COUNT(C) GROUP BY A PIVOT B",1)

Adjust the range as needed.

Sample of test data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZuU-vYBbNyB0HMildyOl1E0Nagc_eRj1JyUMEK1Wleg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you Ed, This seems logical, how do I pass this string to the server though?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. I attached the test sheet I created to the answer. If that doesn't answer your question, provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Hi Ed, My requirement is to populate the pivot programmatically via the Google sheets API for Java. What I am looking for is to create a program that will pull data from a source and populate the excel sheet; and run this as a daily job. I do understand the query written above and the data is similar to mine. But, I am looking for ways to get this done programmatically.

Comment: Hi Anand. The only way I know to create the pivot table with code is to use setFormula to put the query in the spreadsheet. See the code in the script editor of the above sheet. You could use array.length to get the last row (lr) from your imported data. Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer misconstrues the question. The question is about programatically creating a special control with collapsible sections, called a "pivot table". These are commonly created manually using the menus (`Data | Pivot Table`). The word `pivot` as a keyword in the context of a `query` merely causes data that is arranged vertically in the source to appear horizontally in the result. The result in that case is not a pivot table.